# Build a similar VM from an existing VM in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm

I am new to Azure. I have this existing VM. It was built by my colleague and I think he built it through the Marketplace with the Azure portal.

Now I want to build a new one with the same settings (that have the same performance spec) such as the VM sku, OS disk, and data disk. I don't want to keep any existing data. It will be built in a different RG with a different VNet and subnet. What is the best way to do it?

I tried to "export template" on the current VM but I think the JSON file just specifies the existing disks and NIC to use, instead of creating new ones. Here is what it looks like

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "virtualMachines_myCurrentVM_name": {
        "defaultValue": "myCurrentVM",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "disks_myCurrentVM_OsDisk_1_xxxxxx_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-12345678/resourceGroups/nmtprdarmrgp001/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/myCurrentVM_OsDisk_1_xxxxxx",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "disks_myCurrentVM_DataDisk_0_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-12345678/resourceGroups/nmtprdarmrgp001/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/myCurrentVM_DataDisk_0",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "networkInterfaces_myCurrentVM290_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-12345678/resourceGroups/nmtprdarmrgp001/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/myCurrentVM290",
        "type": "String"
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
        "apiVersion": "2021-11-01",
        "name": "[parameters('virtualMachines_myCurrentVM_name')]",
        "location": "westus2",
        "tags": {
            "a": "1",
            "b": "2"
        },
        "plan": {
            "name": "f5-bigiq-virtual-edition-byol",
            "product": "f5-big-iq",
            "publisher": "f5-networks"
        },
        "properties": {
            "hardwareProfile": {
                "vmSize": "Standard_D4_v3"
            },
            "storageProfile": {
                "imageReference": {
                    "publisher": "f5-networks",
                    "offer": "f5-big-iq",
                    "sku": "f5-bigiq-virtual-edition-byol",
                    "version": "latest"
                },
                "osDisk": {
                    "osType": "Linux",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachines_myCurrentVM_name'), '_OsDisk_1_xxxxxx')]",
                    "createOption": "FromImage",
                    "caching": "ReadWrite",
                    "managedDisk": {
                        "storageAccountType": "StandardSSD_LRS",
                        "id": "[parameters('disks_myCurrentVM_OsDisk_1_xxxxxx_externalid')]"
                    },
                    "deleteOption": "Detach",
                    "diskSizeGB": 120
                },
                "dataDisks": [
                    {
                        "lun": 0,
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachines_myCurrentVM_name'), '_DataDisk_0')]",
                        "createOption": "Attach",
                        "caching": "ReadOnly",
                        "writeAcceleratorEnabled": false,
                        "managedDisk": {
                            "storageAccountType": "StandardSSD_LRS",
                            "id": "[parameters('disks_myCurrentVM_DataDisk_0_externalid')]"
                        },
                        "deleteOption": "Detach",
                        "diskSizeGB": 128,
                        "toBeDetached": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            "osProfile": {
                "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachines_myCurrentVM_name')]",
                "adminUsername": "azureuser",
                "linuxConfiguration": {
                    "disablePasswordAuthentication": true,
                    "ssh": {
                        "publicKeys": [
                            {
                                "path": "/home/azureuser/.ssh/authorized_keys",
                                "keyData": "ssh-rsa <some key here>"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "provisionVMAgent": true,
                    "patchSettings": {
                        "patchMode": "ImageDefault",
                        "assessmentMode": "ImageDefault"
                    }
                },
                "secrets": [],
                "allowExtensionOperations": true,
                "requireGuestProvisionSignal": true
            },
            "networkProfile": {
                "networkInterfaces": [
                    {
                        "id": "[parameters('networkInterfaces_myCurrentVM290_externalid')]"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "diagnosticsProfile": {
                "bootDiagnostics": {
                    "enabled": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Is it the best way to edit and modify the JSON file, or there is another way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: How did you deployed the original VM ? through the Azure marketplace ?

Comment: Hey thanks Matan! Someone else deployed it for us. yes - he used an image from the market place. The "export template" does show which image it used. Now we want to re-deploy it in a different RG. Thanks!

Comment: If you will go to the resource group containing that virtual machine and navigate to deployments section, you should see the resource group deployments history.
You can take the template from there.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-history?tabs=azure-portal

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Matan Shabtay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14373720/matan-shabtay). Posting your suggestion as answer to help other community members.

From deployment Section (of the resource group where the VM is currently residing) you would get deployment history. Use that templet to replicate your your VM.

1. Select the **resource group** you want to examine.
   [image]
2. Select the link under **Deployments**.
   [image]
3. Select one of the deployments from the deployment history.
   [image]
4. You can use the view templet option
   [image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-history?tabs=azure-portal